# leetcode 108 Convert Sorted Array to Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, binary-search-tree

When I run this leetcode problem, I used the code below:

```
class Solution {
    public TreeNode sortedArrayToBST(int[] nums) {
        TreeNode root = sortedBST(nums, 0, nums.length-1);
        return root;
    }

    public TreeNode sortedBST(int[]nums, int low, int high){
        if(low > high) return null;
        int temp = (low + high) / 2;
        TreeNode node = new TreeNode(nums[temp]);
        node.left = sortedBST(nums, 0, temp - 1);
        node.right = sortedBST(nums, temp + 1, high);
        return node;

    }
}
```

instead of the correct output 
`[0,-3,9,-10,null,5]` for the sorted array  `[-10,-3,0,5,9]`, 
my output result is `[0,-10,5,null,-3,-3,9,-10,null,-10,0,-3,null,null,null,null,null,-10,null,-10,0,null,-3,null,null,-10,5,-10,null,null,-3,-3,null,null,null,-10,null,-10,0,null,null,null,null,-10,null,null,-3,-10]`.

I'm confused about this results, why it has so many outputs?

Answer (score 1):

Change the line

```
    node.left = sortedBST(nums, 0, temp - 1);
```

To

```
    node.left = sortedBST(nums, low, temp - 1);
```